# Where can I find good, solid documentation for the C++0x synchronization primitives?

Tags: c++, multithreading, documentation, c++11, memory-model

I've seen articles on `::std::thread` and `::std::forward` and such, but I have seen no good articles on `::std::atomic`. There is, of course, the [standards proposal paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html), but I haven't seen any good documentation for someone who just wanted to use the facility.

Is there any? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The just::thread library has decent [documentation](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/) and was developed by [Anthony Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5597/anthony-williams), author of [*C++ Concurrency in Action*](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/book/) and maintainer of the Boost thread library.

Comment: In fact, it explains, in great detail, exactly what the 'memory order' arguments to the various member functions mean.

Comment: You didn't have the concurrency in action link previously, and copied it from the other answer, but you also added the useful hint that the author of the library you pointed at and the book are one and the same, and lent credibility to the book author by linking him to Boost. Yours is the better answer by far.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I got the book link (note the URL) and the other info from the documentation link I had originally.

Comment: @Omnifarious Your link to the gnu online documentation doesn't seem to be what you thought it was (must have changed content). Perhaps update.

Comment: @Walter: Ahh, yes, the various documentation pages get random names that are not stable. *sigh* Here's a link to the list of documentation modules: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/modules.html  - The atomics and concurrency section.

Answer (score 6):

There's also the **[C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/)** book by Anthony Williams.

Comment: Because this interests me so, I went and purchased the early access edition of this book along with a copy of the paper edition when it goes to print. It really does cover the topic thoroughly and well. I'm impressed.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I do have the MEAP edition of the book for some time and reviewed it before posting the answer (didn't post the answer because Google told me so). Glad it was useful for you.