# Why do left operands of logical AND/OR not carry dependency to the parent evaluation?

Tags: c++, atomic, lock-free, stdatomic, carries-dependency

According to C++ standards:

> An evaluation A carries a dependency to an evaluation B if - the value of A is used as an operand of B, unless:
>
> — B is an invocation of any specialization of std::kill_dependency (29.3), or
>
> — A is the left operand of a built-in logical AND (&&, see 5.14) or logical OR (||, see 5.15) operator, or
>
> — A is the left operand of a conditional (?:, see 5.16) operator, or
>
> — A is the left operand of the built-in comma (,) operator (5.18); (...)

I can understand why the dependency ordered before relationship would stop upon kill_dependency call, but why operators such as logical AND, OR, comma, etc. would also break the dependency chain?

Does it mean the code below has undefined behavior?

```
//thread1
int y = 2
atomicVal.store(true);

//thread2 
auto x = atomicVal.load(std::memory_order_consume);
cout << x && y;
```

Comment: One can't find any "logic" or consistent intent in the treatment of consume. It's a trainwreck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`memory_order_consume` was an attempt to expose an asm-level CPU feature for use in C++. (It's [temporarily deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113244/carries-dependency-what-it-means-and-how-to-implement) until it can be reworked to something that compilers can implement in practice, and that doesn't require so much `kill_dependency` noise in the source).  Understanding the CPU behaviour is key to understanding the design of the C++ stuff designed to expose it.

It's all about **data** dependencies, not control dependencies like conditional branches.  [C++11: the difference between memory_order_relaxed and memory_order_consume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280633/c11-the-difference-between-memory-order-relaxed-and-memory-order-consume/59832012#59832012) and [[[carries_dependency]] what it means and how to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113244/carries-dependency-what-it-means-and-how-to-implement) have some more details.

e.g. an `add x2, x2, x3` instruction can't execute until both its input registers are ready, and neither can `ldr w1, [x2]` perform the load until the address is ready, so if `x2` came from another load, it's automatically ordered before this one.  (Assuming CPU hardware is designed not to violate cause-and-effect, e.g. by doing value-prediction or whatever DEC Alpha did to violate causality in rare cases).  But `cbz w1, reg_was_zero` can be predicted, so it's not sufficient to make `reg_was_zero:  ldr w3, [x4]` wait for a load that produced w1.  (This is AArch64 asm, BTW, a weakly-ordered ISA that guarantees dependency-ordering.)

**Short-circuit evaluation of `||` or `left && right` is logically the same as an `if(left) right`**, so branch prediction + speculative execution can be expected to run the right-hand side even if the left-hand side hasn't executed yet.  **There's no data dependency, only a control dependency.**

And obviously comma `left, right` doesn't create any connection at all between the sides, it's basically a way to cram `left; right;` into a single expression.

Of course, if you use the same variable in both left and right sides, a data-dependency can exist that way, but it's not created by the operator.

Comment: Thank you Peter, so did I understand correctly that the snippet I shared is indeed an undefined behavior in theory but safe in practice just because compilers implement consume as acquire?

Comment: @LifuHuang: Is `y` supposed to be a non-atomic variable?  The example would make more sense if thread 1 did `y = 2;` before storing to atomicVal.  Otherwise, if nobody's modifying `y`, it's always safe for any thread to read it!  But yes, if thread 1 modified it then did a release-store to the atomic var, you need at least acquire to avoid the possibility of data-race UB.