# Why release fences added to Scala collections in 2.13 are enough in absence of matching acquire fences?

Tags: scala-collections, memory-barriers, java-memory-model

The process of creation of some of `Scala` immutable collections, most notably `List`, is mutable. In `2.13` the concurrency issues were addressed by adding a *release fence* basically to every builder. A release fence prevents memory writes coming after the fence from being reordered before the fence - so, if you have a 'final write' (such as 'payload_ready' in many examples), it means that anything you wrote (and read) before is commited to shared memory (or at least visible to other threads). When I was reading on fences, I came under impression that a release fence needs a matching *acquire fence* in the code reading the data commited by the other thread. I accepted it as it coincided with an old adage that no synchronisation will work if it happens only at one site (vide the famous 'double-check locking/singleton pattern is broken' warning). I know that Java's (and C++) memory model is more abstract than any contemporary physical architecture, so some aspects of it are irrelevant.

I freely admit that I have no experience with such low-level control as memory barriers, so I do not feel comfortable with using them. In particular, I can't see how writes being reordered *after* a release fence (which, as I understand, is still possible) is any different from writes from after the fence actually happening before it, the latter being forbidden. The fence location is irrelevant, what matters is the *happens-before* relationship. I would like to understand why the lone *release* fence is enough, or ''when'' it is enough, and when in that case an *acquire* fence will still be needed.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `releaseFence` appeared in `List` code as a result of these discussions: [1](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7838) and [2](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6425).
To be fair with you, I didn't find there clear explanations why only `releaseFence` was added (without accompanying `acquireFence`).

---

So I don't know the real answer, but I have a version.

As I understand, `releaseFence` alone ***could*** be enough.
As I've [read](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_what_do_we_have_5) every CPU supported by Java preserves a so called *load dependency*.
It looks like *load dependency* was used to implement `final` JMM guarantees (see [this article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_what_do_we_have_5)), so I guess, Scala might have used the same trick.

Example of *load dependency*:

```java
class Obj {
  int a = 0;
}

Obj obj = null;

void thread1() {
  var o = new Obj();
  o.a = 1;
  VarHandle.releaseFence();
  obj = o;
}

void thread2() {
  Obj o;
  do {
    o = obj;
  } while (o == null)
  var r1 = o.a;
}
```

- In `thread1()`: [releaseFence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#releaseFence()) guarantees that `o.a = 1` and `obj = o` aren't reordered.
- In `thread2()`
  Read `var r1 = o.a` means that we compute memory address for loading as `[memory address of object o] + [offset of field a inside Obj]`.
  This is a *load dependency*: memory address for load `o.a` is computed from memory address of `o` loaded by `o = obj`.
  CPU preserving *load dependency* means that `o = obj` and `var r1 = o.a` aren't reordered.
  Since in `thread1()` `o.a = 1` and `obj = o` aren't reordered either, then read `var r1 = o.a` in `thread2()` is guaranteed to see `1`.

  Note that this works because it's one object:

  - when the value of `obj` changes => we know that `thread1()` is done
  - when we read inner fields of `obj` we get *load dependency* => we are guaranteed to see all the writes from `thread1()` which are before `obj = o`

Here is an example when we need [`acquireFence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#acquireFence()):

```java
int a = 0;
int ready = false;

void thread1() {
  a = 1;
  VarHandle.releaseFence();
  ready = true;
}

void thread2() {
  while (!ready) {;}
  VarHandle.acquireFence(); // required in this case
  var r1 = a;
}
```

Here there is no *load dependency* between the reads of `a` and `ready` in `thread2()`.
As a result `acquireFence` is required to prevent reordering of the reads of `a` and `ready`.

Keep in mind that this is just a version.
As you correctly noted, this all is very low level. I don't know Java on such a deep level.
(BTW as I understand fences are outside the JMM + JMM is defined only for Java (not Scala or JVM) - so I'm not sure that `happens-before` can be applied here, at least as it's defined in the JMM)

Comment: Yup, this makes some sense.  In C++ we'd need `std::memory_order_consume` to make this safe, because C++ is portable to DEC Alpha.  And more importantly, because C++ wants compilers to be able to optimize away things like `x - x` to a `0` without a dependency on the original value in normal cases - it's compiler optimization that's the main challenge for taking advantage of dependency ordering.  (This is a hard problem: current C++ compilers gave up and treat `consume` as a full `acquire`, temporarily deprecating `consume`.)

Comment: But in practice Linux RCU does use this, and the trick is just to write code that doesn't do anything that would let a compile remove a data dependency.  I assume real-world Java can get away with doing this, too.  (See also [\[\[carries\_dependency\]\] what it means and how to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64113244) for more about C++)