# Good resources for developing multithread program with C++0x

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am looking for good books/resources for introducing how to use the thread library  with C++0x. I have searched amazon.com and SO without informative post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a similar question myself recently: [Where can I find good, solid documentation for the C++0x synchronization primitives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938258/where-can-i-find-good-solid-documentation-for-the-c0x-synchronization-primitiv)

And I got back a fantastic answer: *[C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/book/)* by [Anthony Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5597/anthony-williams)

The [JustThread library](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/) at the end of that link also has good Doxygen documentation as well as implementations of a lot of the C++ threading stuff, though it's a commercial library :-/.

Lastly, you can get a [pre-release PDF of this book](http://www.manning.com/williams/). I've gotten it myself, and I can tell you that it's a pretty good book.

gcc/g++ implements more of this than they let on. While it's not yet complete, they have a decent implementation of the classes for threads and futures and they also implement the atomic family of classes which allow for some fairly fine-grained synchronization that you would normally only be able to achieve by somehow getting memory barrier instructions into your code by hand.

Comment: Just::Thread is indeed commercial, and doesn't have a GPL option.

Comment: Oh, and though the native g++ implementation of C++0x threads is coming on in leaps and bounds, it is not a "full implementation" yet.

Comment: @Anthony Williams - There, edited my answer to be more correct per your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there are very few (at least not gcc) that support the thread section of C++0x.

Therefore you have to use boost which closely follows the C++0x specification.

I find that the best resource for using boost libraries is their own online documentation, which can be found at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html.